# Convert an AngularJS app into a "standard" Node.js app to be friendly deployment of Node.js Hosting

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman

Sorry my question is Novice, but I wont to do that in order to be an AngularJS APP friendly of deployment of any Node.js Hosting.

I found something like that by Meteor: "https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer" but i can't found by AngularJS.

Or some way to build with Grunt, for instance: "grunt build node-js" and the "dist" folder containt all the files need to deploy in any NodeJS Hosting like CloudBees.

It is possible something like that?

thanks a lot!
Jero

PD: I do not want to deploy my Angular APP in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but if you are looking to develop with Angular and node, consider http://meanjs.org/, it is a full-featured stack for precisely this application.

You also have  other. MVC frameworks such as sails.js and gedddy.js, or the more barebones express.js